# Ubuntu boots up and becomes unresponsive as soon as I see the desktop

Tags: 12.04

This is happening very frequently with my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I am unable to see anything on the status bar(The ui elements which show wifi strength, battery status etc) and it remains blank. I am unable to do anything and then I have to do a hard reboot after which the problem may/may not persist. How can I rectify this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when when your drivers are not compatible with your hardware.so u need to download the compatible ones.

1. first of all open the grub menu by clicking f6 or f7 when ur PC starts(depending on ur PC)and then open the OS in advanced-> recovery mode and then click on fail safe X mode and if it shows that you are low on graphics,cannot detect screen and devices then the problem will be mostly due to the driver.
2. Now depending on your hardware install the drivers from the internet whether its nvidia drivers or ATI etc.
3. Then go to the setting option->software and updates-> additional drivers->then selct anyone of the drivers and then click on apply changes and then restart your PC.

This will do your work if the problem is with the drivers.

Comment: for detailed description check this out (http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)                                            contains all the description of low graphic mode

Comment: Ok this is my first answer for a question in askubuntu which worked. Feeling good that i am getting some hold of this linux world. Don't forget to vote for my answer.Thankyou for trying it.

Comment: It seems that this was not the proper solution. I am running ubuntu on Dell inspiron laptop with intel graphics card. I did whatever was possible, referred this link as well but the issue still persists and is not consistent : http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error

Comment: Above solution worked for me i.e changing the driver from open source x.org... driver to nvidia driver (proprietery). Have you tried all the drivers present in additional drivers list. Try each of them and reboot. Don't worry if it takes time to cahnge the driver. Before all I dont know much about intel drivers but download appropriate one's checking in the internet and then apply the above changes.